# TextView is not scrolling vertically unless there's a link in it

Tags: android, android-layout

I've enabled vertical scrolling in my TextView that's inside a ScrollView (for the purposes of leaving other content on top when scrolling horizontally) - however vertical scrolling only works when there's a link in TextView's data. If there's no url/email/etc, then vertical scrolling does not work.

When it does work, the vertical scrollbar also reports the wrong scroll position - having scrolled 100% in the view, it'll go to max 5% of the screen.

Here's the problematic xml layout in question that gives this odd behavior, and **newsreader_message** is the one I'd like to be able to scroll properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newsreader_subjectdate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newsreader_fromto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsreader_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web|email"
        android:contentDescription="News post content"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="11.5sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />
</ScrollView>
```

As an additional detail, the marquees don't scroll either when vertical scrolling is broken (and marquees need to scroll).

Answer (score 0):

Change layout_width of textview to "fill_parent" and try once

Comment: I tried changing either the @+id/newsreader_message and the @+id/scrollView1's layout_width to that, but it didn't help.

Comment: once set layout_width="yourscreenresloution+50" i.e., say layout_width = "500dp" and try

Comment: I don't want to do that, the screen resolution can change... doesn't seem like a proper solution.

Comment: i asked to do that just for testing purpose not to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollViews layout should be wrap_content .Another option would be to make the scrollview do the scrolling and textview fill the space as below

```
<ScrollView     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"    
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:scrollHorizontally="true"         
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
android:fillViewport="true" >      
    <TextView         
android:id="@+id/newsreader_message"         
android:layout_width=""fill_parent"        
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
android:autoLink="web|email"         
android:contentDesciption="News post content"        
 android:keepScreenOn="true"         
android:paddingRight="10dp"         
android:paddingTop="6dp"                
  android:text=""        
 android:textSize="11.5sp"        
 android:typeface="monospace"  
android:layout_weight="1.0" /> 
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I'm afraid the layout didn't work, it just made the TextView wrap it's content instead of allowing it to be scrolled horizontally. The content is already pre-wrapped, so Androids wrapping just makes it looks bad.

I tried using android:singleLine to force it not to wrap, but that just makes it all be one line!

Comment: did you put fillViewport="true" ?It will fill the scrollview

Comment: Yeah I copied your xml as-is and corrected the triple quote on layout_width. fillViewport is on.